# What is a plausible etymology of "dosh", a British slang word for money?

Tags: etymology, british-english, slang, money

Neither [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dosh) nor [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=dosh&searchmode=none) seem to know anything.

UPDATED (October 25 2015)

> **dosh** ‎(uncountable)
>
> 1. (Britain, slang) Money
>
> *Etymology Unknown.* Possibly a combination of *dough* and *cash*
>   <sub>Wiktionary</sub>

Comment: I did not even know that word but I found [this page](http://www.businessballs.com/moneyslanghistory.htm) with many more... As for "dosh" the interesting part is "Almost certainly and logically derived from the slang 'doss-house', meaning a very cheap hostel or room, from Elizabethan England when 'doss' was a straw bed, from 'dossel' meaning bundle of straw, in turn from the French 'dossier' meaning bundle. Dosh appears to have originated in this form in the US in the 19th century, and then re-emerged in more popular use in the UK in the mid-20th century."

Comment: watching again the 2005 BBC adaptation of Bleak House, I've come across the phrase "sixpenny doss-houses" (when Lady Dedlock is nowhere to be found and Inspector Bucket lists all the places he has visited to try to find her).  You might have noticed it as well.

Comment: I just don't think that it could possibly came from doss house. It is an Americanized german word of Dosch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chambers Dictionary 11th Ed.:

> ORIGIN: Poss *do*llars and ca*sh*

Partridge Dictionary of Slang:

> Possibly a combination of *dollars* and *cash*; there are also suggestions that the etymology leads back to *doss* (temporary accommodation), hence, it has been claimed, the money required to doss, or Scottish dialect *doss* (tobacco pouch, a purse containing something of value) – note, too, that tobacco is related to money via *quid*. US *dosh* didn’t survive but in mid-C20 UK and Australia the word was resurrected, or coincidentally recoined *US, 1854*

Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary 8th Ed.:

> 1950s: of unknown origin

Oxford English Dictionary:

> Origin unknown.
>
> 1953 H. Clevely *Public Enemy* xviii. 114 He hadn't enough dosh on him.

Comment: +1, nice answer; unfortunately, I'm out of votes for the day...

Comment: My guess would have been that it is cockney-yiddish in origin, but google doesn't turn up anything about that.

Comment: +1 I found a similar explanation in [Eric Partridge's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Partridge) dictionary "[Origins: A Short Etymological Dictionary of Modern English](http://www.amazon.com/Origins-Etymological-Dictionary-Modern-English/dp/0415474337/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1303251400&sr=8-1).

Comment: I’m not sure about the purported link of *dosh* to *doss*. *Doss house* is still a term that is used in England, as is *dosser* (a tramp or a scruffy person) and *doss down* (sleep, usually at a temporary and improvised locale&nbsp;– similar to *crash*). These are pretty distant meanings to money.

Answer (score 2):

Tony Thorne, *The Dictionary of Contemporary Slang* (1990) repeats one of the origin theories that Partridge notes (as quoted in user3286's answer), but also suggests an alternative involving "the African colonial term *dash*":

> **dosh** n *British*[:] money. This is a working-class term from the early 1950s which was falling out of use in the 1960s, but which, like many similar words (**bunce**, **loot**, **lolly**, etc.), was revived in the money conscious late 1980s. It is a favourite with alternative comedians and 'professional cockneys'. The original would seem logically to be the old African colonial term **dash**, denoting a tip or bribe, but other authorities claim that it is influenced by **doss** [defined in its own entry as meaning "a place to sleep," "a period of sleep," or "a very easy task"], in the sense of the price of a bed (for the night).

John Ayto & John Simpson, *The Oxford Dictionary of Modern Slang* (1992), meanwhile, stick to the *OED* line of "origin unknown":

> **dosh** *noun* Money 1953–. ** 'America! The money's in America!' ... ''Tis true. The Yankees have the dosh all right' (1970) {Origin unknown}

Answer (score 0):

DOSH = bangla for TEN that's where it comes from. It was picked up during the time when the The British East India Company was running the show out there, just like CHA was picked up for tea.