# Etymology/history of "dib-dob" as military slang for foreign currency

Tags: etymology, slang, money

*Dib-dob* is used as a generic term for foreign currency (I've come across it for Euros and Dollars).

I've recently heard this used by some RAF types, and had heard it before, from someone presumably influenced by family members in the Royal Navy.  The [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2012/aug/21/guide-to-submarine-slang) has it as submariner's slang, though the naval influence when I heard it was shore-based and, I seem to recall, surface ships.

I don't know whether it's specifically UK military, or even whether it extends to the army (the RAF has some significant naval influences which may be surprising to those who haven't read its history).  I can't find it in any dictionary I've tried online, and Google isn't being much help even with "-scout -scouts". [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dib%20dob) does have a definition (for what it's worth), but a different one "A retarded child. A window licker. A boss eyed dribbler. A Currys or Comet staff member."

I've tried looking at the currencies of places where the Navy (and later RAF)
might have been stationed, but haven't seen anything obvious.
I'm interested to know where it came from and how long it's been around.

Comment: Not sure if it is related to your questions: ***Dibs*** 2. a slang word for money
[C18: shortened from dibstones children's game played with knucklebones or pebbles, probably from dib to tap, dip, variant of dab1]

Comment: @user110518 a connection is quite possible, and would be interesting

Comment: I've never come across this use of ***dib[-]dob***, nor do I recognise ***dibs*** as meaning "money" (per the full OED, it's [*a children's word used to express a **claim or option on some object***.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52151?rskey=KsMW08&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)). But a couple of minutes looking on Google Books and Google Internet suggests there might be a connection to ***Dib-dob-dib*** as used by Baden Powel's Scouts (perhaps through the sense of "small change" earned during ***bob-a-job*** weeks associated with Scout fundraising in the UK).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I may have heard of *dibs* as money in the distant past -- it jogged something when I read user110518's comment -- but the "claim" sense is familiar (I'd call it informal rather than childish in fact).  The scouting link looks a little tenuous but may be worth a bit of digging.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Dyb" and "dob" as used in the Cubs and Scouts relates to the "Grand Howl". I never graduated to Scouts, but in the Cubs each "six" would squat on their haunches and the leader ("sixer") would yell "Dyb, dyb, dyb, dyb" (dyb being an acronym for "do your best"), and in response all the pack would yell "We'll dob, dob, dob, dob" (meaning "we'll do our best"). Pure undefiled innocence, nothing whatever to do with filthy lucre! They were still doing it in the early 1990s when my son was undergoing the ritual.

Comment: The closest term to "dib-dob" that Jonathon Green, _Chanmbers Slang Dictionary_ (2008) lists is the Australian term **dibber-dobber**, dated to "1980s+" and defined as "a tell-tale; a 'whistleblower'." I don't see any obvious connection between that term and the one you ask about. Green says that "dibber-dobber" derives from "dob in" (1950s+)—"to betray, to inform against"—which in turn derives from dialectal "dob"—"to put down with a sharp, abrupt motion." The formal similarity between "dib-dob" and "dibber-dobber" may be purely coincidental.

Comment: @SvenYargs, I've come across that use of *dob* (in London) but couldn't think of a connection. The assonance makes the pairing quite likely so it could really be a coincidence (IMO of course). This seems harder than I expected to pin down

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230956/what-is-the-origin-of-dibs

Comment: @user070221 Ah, but is it? Pinning down that relationship might be an answer.

Comment: It's probably just another case of word pairs which are used together for a common meaning (money),  a common usage (in children's game) and the initial assonance of the letter d.  Just my personal take.

Comment: Possibly related: [“What is a plausible etymology of **dosh**, a British slang word for money?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21430/what-is-a-plausible-etymology-of-dosh-a-british-slang-word-for-money)

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK
**[dob](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dob)** (ODO)

> verb [with object]
>   *NZ, Australian
>
>   informal*
>   **2** (dob something in) Contribute money to a common cause.
>   ‘everyone dobbed in a few dollars’
>   Origin
>   1950s: figurative use of dialect dob ‘put down abruptly’, later ‘throw something at a target’.

---

EDIT
**HMS Ark Royal**'s  [Royal Naval Slang & Terminology](https://arkroyal.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=24&Itemid=145)
Mentions only **Ickies** & **Klebbies** for Foreign money.

Ditto, [Jackspeak: A guide to British Naval slang & usage](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=V4xaDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT266&lpg=PT266&dq=klebbies&source=bl&ots=tnW7WcpKZC&sig=QrwIlZ4XNNxQ1X1kOowPq0y4czQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj968r63bncAhWUeysKHf29BysQ6AEwC3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=foreign%20currency&f=false) (GoogleBooks)

*Commentary:*
I can only extrapolate that *dib-dob* is no more than fanciful reduplication of *dob*.

*See also:*
[What is the origin of “dibs”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/230956/14666) (ELU)

Comment: "*In most of these uses the dialect **dob is synonymous with the more familiar dab**, and with some of that word’s dialectal uses—for example, **a dab can be ‘an amount of money’**, and to dab down means ‘to put a thing down quickly’ and figuratively ‘to pay down ready money’*. - http://languagehat.com/the-story-of-dob/

Comment: Actually, the sense of "money" was present both in dib and in dob (dab).

Comment: Funnily enough I'd seen a discussion about that HMS Ark Royal page on a naval forum, because someone commented about the omission of Dibdob.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can't find anything else online about anyone *actually using* “dib-dob,” but as far as its presumptive etymology:

Every applicable sense<sup><sub>¹</sub></sup> of “dib” or “dob” in the OED traces its origin back to **dialectical variants of “dab**,**”** usually with the intention of making the referenced pat of something somewhat smaller. The game **dibstones**, played with sheep knuckles as a kind of [jacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knucklebones), led both to Americans “calling dibs” and to **dibs** meaning

> **3.** *plural.* A slang term for money.
>
> > > 1812 H. Smith & J. Smith *Rejected Addr.* 111
> > >
> > > > Make nunky surrender his dibs.

So ultimately on both sides it refers to small dabs or pats of something. The word [“dab”](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/46758) itself shows up in Middle English with no apparent predecessor and seems to come from onomatopoeic imitation of the sound (now **splat**) of a small dab of something being flicked down.

<sup><sub>¹ [“dib, *v.¹*,”](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52153) is a variant of “dip” in reference to any small lowering. [“dib, *n.¹*,”](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52150) is a variant of “dip” in reference to a piece of land that dips down. [“ dib, *n.³*,”](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52152) is a variant of “dub” in reference to puddles of water.</sub></sup>